# More than 4 players in Terrorist Hunt and Campaign?

Tags: rainbow-six-vegas-2

I have a group (more than 4) of players that would like to play Terrorist Hunt together in Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Vegas 2. We are using the steam version. Is there a way that enables us to break the limits on numbers of players allowed in a LAN or campaign game?